# Spring. security. How to add authorities to userAuthentication after oaut2 auhtentication

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, roles, spring-security-oauth2

In my app authentication implemented like this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ . After authetication from third party server redirect to my app. And i need to load roles from local db and add it roles to authenticated user from third party server but this user already exit authority.
How can i do it? 
Thanks.